# this is cake divider problem which i was solving on codechef and i am getting output none

Tags: python, function, loops, oop

#this is a cake division problem on code chef

```
def cake(N):
    if 360%N ==0:
        a ="yes cake can be cut into equal pieces of equal angle"
    else:
        a = "no cake cannot be cutted into equal pieces"
    if N>360:
        b = "cake cannot be cutted becuase number is greater than angle"
    else:
        b = "cake can cuted into n pieces which are not equal"
    if N>26:
        c = "No cake can't be cutted such that no two pieces are  equal"
    else:
        c = "yes cake can be cutted such that two pieces are eqaul"
        return x

T =int(input())
for i in range(T):
    N = int(input())
    print(cake(N))
```

#solve this problem
#output is none
'''i have been trying this problem from so long but unable to find the answer for the problem'''

Comment: instead of doing a="..." you your be returning those strings.

Answer (score 1):

`return` the string instead.

````
    if 360%N ==0:
        return "yes cake can be cut into equal pieces of equal angle"```
````